# Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean calls 'Field.getType'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I am using ProGuard with my Android Studio Project. When I build my release I get the following note:

```
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean calls 'Field.getType'
```

Here is my Gradle config:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Here is proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontnote org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver
-dontnote org.apache.http.conn.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.params.**
-dontnote android.net.http.**

-dontnote **ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
```

**How can I solve the problem of this note?**

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

*Explanation:*

Your note has nothing to do wit android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean specifically, but with Field.getType.

The method [getType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()) belongs to `java.lang.reflect.Field` of the reflection package, and might access meta information stored in Java class files. However, this meta information is removed by proguard (without the rule above)--therefore the warning.

See also the [attributes](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/attributes.html) that can be used with `-keepattributes`. For attribute **Signature** is said the following:

> Specifies the generic signature of the class, field, or
>   method. Compilers may need this information to properly compile
>   classes that use generic types from compiled libraries.
>   **Code may access this signature by reflection.**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your ProGuard config:

```
-dontnote android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean
```

`NotificationCompatJellybean` gets type of a private `Notification.extras` fields in its `getExtras()` method. But as this field in `Notification` class from Android SDK you can just ignore this note with a command above.